# English, several localizations, how to get rid of them?

Tags: 14.04, gui, language-support

For Ubuntu with English GUI language several English localizations are installed, like New Zealand, Ireland, Australia, Canada and so on. However only en_US is needed. How to achieve this goal? We doubt it was a mainstream who asks for english gui in its all variants.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get rid of them easily, since all the English variants are shipped in the same set of language packs in Ubuntu. My advice would be to select en_US and leave it at that. The other installed English variants do no harm, do they?

Answer (score 0):

You can install localepurge to purge all the useless locale info and translations that are not the same as the locale (en_US) used. To install this, open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install localepurge
```

follow the instructions.

Also, whenever you install new applications in the future, the foreign locale info (non en_US translations) will be deleted upon installation.

*Edit:*

<quote from "man localepurge">

**A Word of CAUTION**

Please note, **that this tool is a hack  which  is  not  integrated  with
Debian's  package  management system** and therefore is not meant for the
faint of heart.  Responsibility for its usage and possible breakage  of
your system therefore lies in the sysadmin's (your) hands.
Please   definitely   do   abstain  from  reporting  any  bugs  blaming
localepurge if **you** break your system by using it.  If  you  don't  know
what  you are doing and can't handle any resulting breakage on your own
then please simply don't use it.

</quote>

Comment: personally, i've never run into any serious problems. every once in a while the system might complain but nothing serious.